# What is "above" and what is "below" the surface of a sphere?

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics, boundary-conditions, conventions

When studying Electromagnetism using D.J. Griffith's Introduction to Electrodynamics, the boundary conditions for the electric potential across a surface charge density are expressed using the normal derivative of the potential, above and below, the surface.

Now my question arises: What is above, and what is below the surface of a sphere. Or in other words, what is the direction of the surface normal vector?

I would have the vector pointing outwards, away from the center, and thus regard above as outside the sphere and below as inside.

However, this seems not always to be the case?

Is there a general rule to figuring out this sign problem?

Comment: In spherical coordinates the "radius" is always by convention positive.  if R-r > 0 inside, if R-r < 0 outside.  Normal to the surface is in the direction of R.  tangent is always perpendicular to the direction of R.

Comment: I agree. The surface vector points out of a sphere and by convention out of any closed surface.

Comment: You say "this seems not always to be the case." Can you give an example that gives rise to your question?

Comment: I am currently doing some previous exam sets in my electromagnetism course, and in one problem I find the potential inside and outside a non conducting sphere with a bound surface charge.

Then I use the afore mentioned boundary condition to calculate the surface charge, however the sign depends on the direction of the normal vector. 

In the solution to the set, the potentials are subtracted in the reverse order to what would be the case with n in the direction of the r unit vector in spherical coordinates.